# How to get the value of "General -> Date & Time -> Set Automatically" programmatically in the iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I would like to know the "Set Automatically" value programmatically so I can validate the launch of my app. That could tell me if the time is reliable or not and further continue my app operations.

I don't want to change the value, just would like to know what's its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get the value of that setting. Even if you could, it wouldn't mean anything at times because the user could be out of cell coverage meaning the time may not be accurate anyway.